# I need to deserialize JSON string

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
string json = @" {""data"":[{""Name"":""Yaj"",""Number"":""null"",""Name"":""null"",""PhotoUrl"":""http://worldforme.com/rfr/fr"",""date"":""1994-06-14 00:00:00.000"",""ID"":""178"",""ssid"":""1"",""InOut"":""Incoming"",""Intime"":""null"",""OutTime"":""null"",""Por"":""null""}]}";

var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mainlist>(json);
```

But dt returns null !

Please help

Comment: Can you post your 'mainlist' class?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mainlist` class needs to be structured to fit the key values of the json string.

Here's an example:

```
public class mainlist
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Number {get; set;}
     [JsonProperty("PhotoUrl")] //Notice how this is different from the property name?
                                //This is because the property needs to fit exactly with the json string.
     public string PhotoURL {get; set;}
     //...
}
```

And if you still can't get it, well then there's something wrong with your json string.

Comment: Yes he did? It's called mainlist, he put the type.

Comment: Idk about the downvote, but ah, it was there, just your browser optimized it away as an html code. Got it.